# Calling external JTW authentication REST webservice from salesforce

Tags: jwt

I need to call external JWT  based REST Webservice from salesforce. I am trying to generate JWT and post it to the given endpoint of webservice. However, while generating JWT, i am not exactly aware about following parameters.

Issuer - Who will be the issuer. How to get/generate this information.
Cert - Will I get certificate from external webservice or I need to generate it, If I need to generate it then how?
Subject - What is subject. How can I get this information.
Audience - What is Audience.How to get this information.

Please let me know with these details.

Thank You!
Nikhil Khandare

Comment: I can't imagine you're supposed to create your own JWT. Ususally you'll authenticate yourself with your user credentials and then get a token that you'll send in the Authorization header of your requests.

Comment: No.. for JWT authentication we need to create JWT and sent it to endpoint which will verify it and return the access token